# Kentico 9 sync Server Service URL case sensitivity

Tags: iis-7, kentico

I have a rewrite rule to make the URL all lower case. It ran before anything else. Site would load fine, things were good, but sync was broken. After some trial and errors I figured it was the rewrite rule. I also tried the build in rule for this with IIS and same issues.

With that, is it possible to make a change so the path is all lower case? I didn't think this would have been an issue but it seems to be.

Here is my rule

```
 <rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content Sync isn't case sensitive that I'm aware of.  You can use the setting within Kentico to do the same as the IIS rewrite rule with no effect on the other system pages.  Have you looked into this? I'd make this edit before making a rewrite rule in IIS.

Settings>URLs & SEO>SEO - URLs>Redirect invalid case URLs to their correct versions = lower case.

Comment: Thanks. It's odd the IIS rule breaks this. I had mine, and then the built in rule first and sync would get the site moved error. I remove the rule and it works. But with the SEO setting, all is good. In the end it work. Cheers!